# Why there is no ring hom from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $\Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Why there is no ring hom from $\Bbb{Z}_p$ to $\Bbb{Z}$?

Let $f:\Bbb{Z}_p→ \Bbb{Z}$ be a ring hom.

My try:
In the case of $p＝5$, f:$\Bbb{Z}_5→\Bbb{Z}$ should take $\sqrt -1$(it exists because of Hensel lemma) to $-1/2$, but it is not integer.
Is this correct ?

In any way, I should take some good element of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and find contradiction, how can I do that correctly ?

Comment: From that what kind of contradiction occur? We just take 1 in p adic integer to 1 in integer ring suffices, I think.

Comment: In $\mathbb Z_2$, $f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=2\ne 0\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @JohnDouma It's not very explicitly stated, but this is about $p$-adics, not modulo $p$. It's hidden away in the tags.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4390843/96384

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the $p$-adic integers, there are many multiplicatively invertible elements (such as $p+1$). Where could your homomorphism possibly send them?

Comment: $f(1＋p)＝1＋f(p)$, if I could prove $f(p)$ cannot become $0$ or $-2$, I can finish the proof , but how can I prove that ?

Comment: Consider $p=1+1+\cdots+1$, and apply $f$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's it. $f(1＋p)＝1＋p$, but $1＋p$ is not invertible in integer ring, this is contradiction.